# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined - JAVA Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am new in starting up spring projects and i have the problem from title.

I don't know how can i resolve it, i have the same configuration and files to start up spring in other project and there it works. Here not and i don't know why.

my code is :

maven
`
    demo
    demo
    1.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<properties>
    <javax.trans.ver>1.1</javax.trans.ver>
    <javax.ver>2.5</javax.ver>
    <spring.base.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.base.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.data.ver>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring.data.ver>
    <hib.core.ver>4.3.10.Final</hib.core.ver>
    <hib.jpa.supp.ver>4.3.10.Final</hib.jpa.supp.ver>
    <hib.val.ver>5.1.3.Final</hib.val.ver>
    <mysql.conn.ver>5.1.6</mysql.conn.ver>
    <junit.ver>4.12</junit.ver>
    <jstl.verion>1.2</jstl.verion>
    <cglib.version>3.1</cglib.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.trans.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring stuff-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.base.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.base.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.base.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.base.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.base.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.base.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.ver}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--My sql conn-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.conn.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hib.core.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hib.jpa.supp.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hib.val.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Junit-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.verion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Stuff-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

`

spring security initializer:

```
package ro.stefan.configs;

    import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

    public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    }
```

spring security config:

```
package ro.stefan.configs;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import ro.stefan.serv.UsersDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UsersDetailsServiceImpl usersDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("stefan").password("1234").roles("USER");
        auth.userDetailsService(usersDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/res/**");
    }

    //.csrf() is optional, enabled by default, if using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter constructor
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/main/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/admin").failureUrl("/admin?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/admin?logout")
                .and()
                .csrf();
      //  http.formLogin().loginPage("/admin/login").failureUrl("/admin/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/main",true).usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");

    }
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Demo App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/servletConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

servletConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="ro.stefan" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="WEB-RES/" mapping="/res/**" />

</beans>
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: In your web.xml springSecurityFilterChain filter mapping is missing.

Comment: I have to downvote and apologize for that... but the problem of confusing root vs servlet context config is asked and answered here on SO at least once a week. Please follow the official documentation and **don't use** or mix old tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Can you put springSecurityFilter chain -

e.g.,

```
<context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>  
            classpath:/jpaContext.xml,  
            /WEB-INF/servletConfig.xml  
        </param-value>  

    </context-param>  
    <!-- Spring Security -->  

    <filter>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
    </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This document helps a lot http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html#delegating-filter-proxy

Answer (score -3):

Why you don't try code generators like spring-boot ( https://start.spring.io/ ) or jhipster https://jhipster.github.io/ ?
They should generate all code needed driven by best practices and with minimal configuration on your side. it's perfect for starting point